# Urchin call add a custom one time user parameter

Tags: urchin

I am using urchin for page view analysis. While page load, I would like to add a new custom parameter like  along with the other default parameters that urchin sends. Is there any easy way to do it without addint myparam to the request URLs?

```
http://utm.trk.mydomain.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=6.1&utmn=49500369&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmjv=1.5&utmfl=10.1%20r85&utmdt=MyWebSearch&utmhn=mydomain.com&utmr=0&utmp=/mypage?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling urchinTracker with specific path that I want to log at the page load time. This solved the problem.